# Use Google Scripts to insert random numbers into Column G if Column A is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a script that will look at the values in Column A of my Google sheet and for each cell of Column A that is not blank, a random number is generated and put into the corresponding cell of Column G. (I've looked up many variations of this, but most people are looking for how to generate numbers between a specific range, which isn't important for me)
Thank You!

Edit: I have continued searching, I found some things but I don't know how to put it together. (I am not a programmer, I know that this won't work, but I don't know how to fix it) This is what I have so far:

```
function randNum() {

  var sheetName = 'FilterEmergMerge';
  var col1 = 0; 
  var col2 = 6; 

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  data.forEach(function(e, i) {

if (e[col1].toString.length > 0){
    col2=cell.setValue(Math.random());
}      
  });
}
```

Comment: loop thru A, put a value of Math.random() if A not empty.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply Arno, I appreciate it, but I'm not a programmer, I need the actual programming (I'm helping with volunteer efforts with a nonprofit because I know how to use Google sheets, but I found that what I need to do needs a script and I can't do that :)  Thanks again

Comment: I understand but be aware that SO is not a service that writes your code for you, rather it is a Q&A platform.

Answer (score 0):

**This might work better if you have formulas in other cells.**

```
function randNum() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var fA = rg.getFormulas();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][0]){
      vA[i][6]=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)/100;
    }
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
      if(fA[i][j].slice(0,1) == '='){
        vA[i][j]=fA[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  sh.getDataRange().setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: If A is blank, no random number. You should also hint how to write the new values back to the sheet (and not just into an array). I might suggest only writing column G, rather than the whole data range since there are probably formulas.